# Laptop Battery: Can High Voltage Damage?

Tags: battery, voltage

I am looking to buy a new battery for my Toshiba Satellite L10 But I have a problem. On the website, it says only compatible with 14.4 /14.8 volts, but my computer is 19 volt. Does this matter? Will it still Work with my computer? Can I buy it?

Comment: It isn't really clear which voltages you're referring to.  The charger puts out a certain voltage, the laptop may specify a different voltage, and the battery can be a third voltage (and that can all be normal).  To give you a reliable and definitive answer, it would help if you edit the question to include the actual laptop model.

Answer (score 0):

If your battery is 19 volts it won't work (or won't work properly and is not a good idea).   If the power supply is 19 volts, thats not a problem as the battery voltage is not the same as the power supply voltage.